# Making a single character immortal in a minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I am setting up a Minecraft server which will feature a single player who is very averse to dying. Does anyone know of a way to have a forge-modded survival server where a single character is immortal, but the rest functions as normal? Extra points if that character can also be setup to do 0 damage to others.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here with a somewhat OK solution, but i would still very much like to hear better/alternative solutions.

It is possible to use the /effect command to give resistance 5 to a player. Resistance reduces damage by 20% pr level, so it SHOULD make characters invulnerable at level 5. The effect can be made semi-permanent as far as I can see, by giving a long duration. A /kill command will still kill the player, as will void damage.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resistance

https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/effect_command.php

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command `/effect [Username] resistance 255 600` to make the player take no damage for 10 minutes, and the command `/effect [Username] weakness 255 600` for the player to do no damage for 10 minutes